# Problems implementing a cache/proxy by means of Californium library

Tags: coap, californium

I'd like to implement a proxy/cache server using californium Library. The problem is that I have no references about how to use it. Could you give some advice/tips or link me some manual or tutorial? I would appreciate a lot. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this repository?

https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/californium-proxy

Also the examples:

https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/cf-proxy

Comment: I've checked but that examples is "only" a proxy. I was wondering how to implement a cache service.. I'll figure something out. Eventually. Hopefully

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, Eclipse/Californium contains a redesigned proxy2. See [Proxy 2, README](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/californium-proxy2), for more details. It uses com.google.guava:guava:28.2 to implement the cache function.